Problem with merging rasters in QGIS
I merged rasters in QGIS, and the resulting image appears like this. The minimum value is -3.40282e+38, which seems incorrect. How can I solve this issue?


-3.40282e+38 is probably the value for nodata cells. Use Fill NoData Cells: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#fill-nodata to define a value for these cells.

You can just enter 0 in the field with the min-Value (the red underlined in your Image) to stretch it.
